# Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read) when sending request to Django on Heroku

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku, python-requests

I have a view that returns a JsonResponse in Django

```
def some_view(request):
    return JsonResponse({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

And somewhere else in side the same project, I have a piece of code that sends a GET request to the url corresponds to that view:

```
import requests
def client_func():
    requests.get(url_to_some_views)
```

It works on my local machine but after deploying to heroku, sometimes I get the error: `('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))`

After some testing, I found out that there is an extra field in the response header of `some_view`: `transfer-encoding: chunked` so I guess it might be what caused the problem but I'm still not sure how to handle this. So far I have tried to add `stream=True` to the get call in `client_func` but the problem still persists.

Can someone help me with that might be the cause of my problem and to solve this please. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem, it was because 1 of my GET requests has a body and it messed things up.